# lxml/Python : get previous-sibling

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following html:

```html
<div id = "big">
    <span>header 1</span>
    <ul id = "outer">
        <li id = "inner">aaa</li>
        <li id = "inner">bbb</li>
    </ul>

    <span>header 2</span>
    <ul id = "outer">
        <li id = "inner">ccc</li>
        <li id = "inner">ddd</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want it to loop it in the order:

```
header 1
aaa
bbb
header 2
ccc
ddd
```

I have tried looping through each ul and then printing the header and the li values. However, I don't know how to get the span header that is associated with a ul.

```
sets = tree.xpath("//div[@id='big']//ul[@id='outer']")

for set in sets:

    # Print header. Not sure how to get it
    header = set.xpath(".//li/preceding-sibling::span")
    print header 
    
    # Print texts. This works.
    values = set.xpath(".//li//text()")
    for v in values:
        print v
```

Just looping all text nodes won't work because I need to know if it is a header or li value.

Comment: Not directly impacting the question, but this is bad HTML because IDs should be unique. You could use `class="outer"` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked:

```
header = ingred_set.getprevious().xpath(".//text()")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTML use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup). It gives you [access to previous and next siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) directly:

```
sibling_soup.b.next_sibling
# <c>text2</c>

sibling_soup.c.previous_sibling
# <b>text1</b>
```

Also, you can tell BS to use `lxml` parser in [constructor](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). From practice I can tell that `lxml` performs better than the default `html.parser` on ill-formatted input

Comment: I'm no longer a fan of beautifulSoup. It's way slower than lxml and I kept running into issues and limitations.

Comment: I actually never hit any serious limits in BS. Out of curiosity, can you give some examples?