# How to use lxml in Python to get the following elements?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, xml.etree

I have the next XML file:

```
<separator colspan="4" string="Application"/>
<field name="sel_groups_9_28_10" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_49_50" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_68" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_36_37" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_21_22_23" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_43_44" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_5_57_58" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_59_60" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_61_62" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_19" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<field name="sel_groups_3_4" modifiers="{}"/>
<newline/>
<separator colspan="4" string="MY GROUP"/>
<field name="in_group_144" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_142" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_148" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_147" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_146" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_145" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_141" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_143" modifiers="{}"/>
<separator colspan="4" string="Technical configuration"/>
<field name="in_group_30" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_46" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_12" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_45" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_33" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_66" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_25" modifiers="{}"/>
<field name="in_group_32" modifiers="{}"/>
```

The common structure of the tree is:

```
<separator 1/>
<field 1/>
<field 2/>
<field N/>
<separator 2/>
<field 1/>
<field 2/>
<field N/>
<separator N/>
<field 1/>
<field 2/>
<field N/>
```

What I want is to get the separators whose string is different from *MY GROUP* and from all the following fields until the next separator (My purpose is to make every element invisible except for the separator *MY GROUP* and the fields *in_group_144*, *in_group_142*, *in_group_148*, *in_group_147*, *in_group_146*, *in_group_145*, *in_group_141* and *in_group_143*).

The XML tree will vary its field names, so get the fields by their names will not be a solution.

Here [lxml/Python : get previous-sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262532/lxml-python-get-previous-sibling) gives how to get the previous sibling, but how could I get the previous sibling whose tag is *separator* in an efficient way?

My current solution:

```
def get_previous_separator(self, element):
    previous_element = element.getprevious()
    if previous_element.tag == 'separator':
        return previous_element
    else:
        return get_previous_separator(element)

for element in tree:
    if self.get_previous_separator(element).string != 'MY GROUP':
        MAKE ELEMENT INVISIBLE
```

Is there any way more direct than a recursive method to manage my target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple XPath to get the nearest preceding sibling `separator` element from current `element` :

```
element.xpath('preceding-sibling::separator[1]')
```